# Converting rows into columns and header using R

Tags: r, tidyverse, multiple-columns, rows, transpose

Hi have a text file summary.txt that looks like this

```
snp_fp_overlapp_count: 0
snp_fn_overlapp_count: 0
snp_fn_ca_overlapp_count: 0
snp_fn_ca_0: 0
indel_fp_overlapp_count: 0
indel_fn_overlapp_count: 0
indel_fn_ca_overlapp_count: 0
indel_fn_ca_0: 0
-------------------------------------
snp_hard_count: 0
indel_hard_count: 0
unknown_count: 0
-------------------------------------
total_baseline_snp: 12405
total_baseline_indel: 1137
-------------------------------------
Precision_SNP: 0.790329
Sensitivity_SNP: 0.972350
F_Measure_SNP: 0.871941
-------------------------------------
Precision_INDEL: 0.119915
Sensitivity_INDEL: 0.941073
F_Measure_INDEL: 0.212724
-------------------------------------
Annotation Percent Match:
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
```

I need to convert the metric names as column and its values as 2nd row in R, snippet below

```
Precision_INDEL Sensitivity_INDEL   F_Measure_INDEL
0.119915    0.941073    0.212724
```

Not sure how to go about this, i've been struggling with tidyverse that doesn;t seem to be the solution

```
mydata = read_table("summary.txt")

mydata %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -rowname) %>% 
  separate(variable ,sep = ":",into = c("metric","value")) %>%
  spread(rowname, value)
```

Any pointers/solutions would be useful

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need? I am not sure exactly what you mean 'in table format'.

```
dat = data.table::fread('snp_fp_overlapp_count: 0
snp_fn_overlapp_count: 0
snp_fn_ca_overlapp_count: 0
snp_fn_ca_0: 0
indel_fp_overlapp_count: 0
indel_fn_overlapp_count: 0
indel_fn_ca_overlapp_count: 0
indel_fn_ca_0: 0
snp_hard_count: 0
indel_hard_count: 0
unknown_count: 0
total_baseline_snp: 12405
total_baseline_indel: 1137
Precision_SNP: 0.790329
Sensitivity_SNP: 0.972350
F_Measure_SNP: 0.871941
Precision_INDEL: 0.119915
Sensitivity_INDEL: 0.941073
F_Measure_INDEL: 0.212724
Annotation Percent Match:
', sep=" ")
```

```
a = dat %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from="V1", values_from="V2")
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 19
  `snp_fp_overlapp_co… `snp_fn_overlapp_co… `snp_fn_ca_overlapp_… `snp_fn_ca_0:`
                 <dbl>                <dbl>                 <dbl>          <dbl>
1                    0                    0                     0              0
# … with 15 more variables: indel_fp_overlapp_count: <dbl>,
#   indel_fn_overlapp_count: <dbl>, indel_fn_ca_overlapp_count: <dbl>,
#   indel_fn_ca_0: <dbl>, snp_hard_count: <dbl>, indel_hard_count: <dbl>,
#   unknown_count: <dbl>, total_baseline_snp: <dbl>,
#   total_baseline_indel: <dbl>, Precision_SNP: <dbl>, Sensitivity_SNP: <dbl>,
#   F_Measure_SNP: <dbl>, Precision_INDEL: <dbl>, Sensitivity_INDEL: <dbl>,
#   F_Measure_INDEL: <dbl>
```

```
> colnames(a)
 [1] "snp_fp_overlapp_count:"      "snp_fn_overlapp_count:"     
 [3] "snp_fn_ca_overlapp_count:"   "snp_fn_ca_0:"               
 [5] "indel_fp_overlapp_count:"    "indel_fn_overlapp_count:"   
 [7] "indel_fn_ca_overlapp_count:" "indel_fn_ca_0:"             
 [9] "snp_hard_count:"             "indel_hard_count:"          
[11] "unknown_count:"              "total_baseline_snp:"        
[13] "total_baseline_indel:"       "Precision_SNP:"             
[15] "Sensitivity_SNP:"            "F_Measure_SNP:"             
[17] "Precision_INDEL:"            "Sensitivity_INDEL:"         
[19] "F_Measure_INDEL:"           
> as.numeric(a[1,])
 [1]     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000
 [6]     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000
[11]     0.000000 12405.000000  1137.000000     0.790329     0.972350
[16]     0.871941     0.119915     0.941073     0.212724
```

Comment: Thank you. I have several text files in a similar format as shown above that I need to read in R for further analysis. I meant to have the metric names as column names and its values on the 2nd row

Comment: @nbn - I think that's what I've done there - the colnames are the metrics and the first row is the value.

Comment: The values are not included in the first row, I think even in your solution...Using the above code from @user438383

`mydata = read.csv(file="summary.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ":" )
mydata f %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from="V1", values_from="V2")`


results in 

`snp_tp_0
<list>
snp_fn_0
<list>
snp_fp_0
<list>
snp_fp_hethom_count
<list>
snp_fp_vardiff_count
<list>
snp_fp_plus_fn
<list>
basepairs
<list>
total_baseline_variants
<list>
<dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>`

Comment: Which values aren't included in the first row? The resulting data.frame has 19 columns which is the same number of rows as values as the data you gave me. Are you confused because the tibble doesn't show all the values?

Comment: You said 'metric names as column and its values as 2nd row in R'. That's exactly what I've given you.